# UIScrollView - content goes out bound when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I design the scrollview in interface builder like this

[image]

It looks good here. But unfortunately when I run it on emulator or device

it becomes

[image]

The content in scrollview is expand outside scrollview itself and even though outside UIView that contains this scrollView.

In my viewDidLoad (panel is the container of scrollView )

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    CGFloat adjustPanelHeight = [PTTScreenScaleUtil getAdjustHeight:self.panel.frame.size.height];
    CGRect panelRect = self.panel.frame;
    panelRect.size.height = adjustPanelHeight;
    self.panel.frame = panelRect;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"panel-background"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.panel.frame.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.panel.frame.size.width, adjustPanelHeight)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self.panel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage]];

    NSLog(@"scrollView Height : %f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"scrollView contentSize Height : %f", self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
//    CGRect scrollViewRect = self.scrollView.frame;
//    CGRect scrollViewContentRect = self.scrollView.frame;
//    NSLog(@"ScrollView Height Before : %f , After : %f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height, [PTTScreenScaleUtil getAdjustHeight:self.scrollView.frame.size.height]);
//    scrollViewRect.size.width = 280;
//    scrollViewRect.size.height = [PTTScreenScaleUtil getAdjustHeight:270];
//    self.scrollView.frame = scrollViewRect;
//    [self.detailsLabel sizeToFit];
    UIView *view = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
//    [view sizeToFit];
//    [self.scrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
//    NSLog(@"ContentSize Height : %f", view.frame.size.height);
//    scrollViewContentRect.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Bounds : %f", view.bounds.size.height);
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 270);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 500);
    NSLog(@"Frame Height %f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    //[self.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(280, 1000)];

    CGRect termBtnRect = self.termBtn.frame;
    CGRect mailBtnRect = self.mailBtn.frame;
    CGRect twitterBtnRect = self.twitterBtn.frame;
    CGRect fbBtnRect = self.fbBtn.frame;
    termBtnRect.origin.y = adjustPanelHeight - 10 - termBtnRect.size.height;
    mailBtnRect.origin.y = adjustPanelHeight - 10 - termBtnRect.size.height;
    twitterBtnRect.origin.y = adjustPanelHeight - 10 - termBtnRect.size.height;
    fbBtnRect.origin.y = adjustPanelHeight - 10 - termBtnRect.size.height;
    self.termBtn.frame = termBtnRect;
    self.mailBtn.frame = mailBtnRect;
    self.twitterBtn.frame = twitterBtnRect;
    self.fbBtn.frame = fbBtnRect;
}
```

All the log return 270.0

PS. the scroll bar is correct even though the content goes outside but the scroll bar is working correctly (stay in the scrollview's frame as arrange in interface builder)
I have no idea how can I solve this.
Anyone help me please.

Thanks you.

Comment: Are you changing the frame for the scrollView anywhere else in your code?

Comment: no change of the scrollView size (this line self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 270); I just give the same value as i set scrollView in Size Inspector). All those adjustHeight is for iphone5. Below iphone5, it returns the same value.

Comment: Try creating and adding a scrollView programmatically to see if you get the same problem. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solve it by creating new view controller in interface builder and redo the same process with careful and bingo. It works.

When I compare both two view controller I realise that the wrong one UIScrollView Clip Subviews is unchecked. When check it the problem solve.

Comment: Apparently setting the Clip Subviews on the UISCrollView does the trick. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Setting clip to bounds worked for me too but for some reason the setting did not stick when set in the IB. Setting the clipsToBounds = true in the code helped tho

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with this for an hour and had a head smack moment.

In my case, I had a `UIView` on the scene in the Storyboard. At some point I decided I needed it to be a `UIScrollView` instead (as opposed to the original plan which was to embed the `UIScrollView` in a `UIView`)

I went ahead and changed the class on the `UIView` to `UIScrollView`. IB changed it to Scroll View in the Document Outline, I figure I'm good, right?

And then I see the behavior you describe.

At some point it hits me that this isn't sufficient. Apparently adding a `UIScrollView` via IB does some things differently than adding a `UIView` and just changing class isn't enough. And this is probably the reason re-doing it from scratch fixed it for you.

So for anyone who runs into this in the future, make sure you added the `UIScrollView` via IB instead of a `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as described in this post. I tried multiple combinations of solutions that did not work, including:

- putting the scroll view inside a view with Clip To Bounds = YES
- putting a view inside the scroll view with Clip To Bounds = YES, that then contained my child view
- putting a Container View inside the scroll view, and then embedding my subview
- rebuilding the Interface Builder files completely
- every combination of autosizing mask options systematcially for both the scroll view and container view
- clip to bounds enabled or disabled for every single element systematically

The child view in question had previously worked inside a scroll view, but wouldn't in this one case where the content blew outside the bounds of the scroll view.

In the end, I implemented the solution in code as I could find no way to get Interface Builder to co-operate:

```
// There are two scroll areas on the screen, the left view and the right view.
// We want the right view to contain a scrollable area with another child view controller
// we designed in Interface Builder.

// create a scroll view to fill the right view with a scrollable area
CGSize rightFrameSize = self.rightView.bounds.size;
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, rightFrameSize.width, rightFrameSize.height)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 1352);
[self.rightView addSubview:scrollView];

// now create our child view controller from Interface Builder and add it to the scroll view
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CustomerAddress" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
detailsView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomerDetailsView"];
detailsView.delegate = self;
detailsView.customer = _customer;
[scrollView addSubview:detailsView.view];
```

You could of course get the scrollView.contentSize from the child view controller you constructed in Interface Builder using `scrollView.contentSize = detailsView.view.frame.size`.

I have a love/hate relationship with Interface Builder... most days I love it, but some days we argue and I wish we'd never met... :)

Answer (score 0):

only make cliptobound=YES in storyboard if you changed UIView to UIScrollView